# Send data on key 'Enter' - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, components

I'm trying to send my `fieldset` when I press Enter, but my function does not return my `console.log`

Here is a fragment of my component :

```
{formIncomes === false && (
                        <div className="text-left flex justify-items-center relative">
                            <form onSubmit={handleAddIncome} className="m-auto">
                                <label htmlFor="newIncomeName"></label>
                                <input className="w-38 bg-gray-50 shadow-inner italic p-1 m-1 text-gray-500 text-xs" id="newIncomeName"
                                    name="newIncomeName"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={incomeCall}
                                    onChange={(e) => setIncomeCall(e.target.value)}
                                    onClick={handleClearIncomeCall}
                                />

                                <label htmlFor="newIncomeAmount"></label>
                                <input className="w-38 shadow-inner italic p-1 m-1 text-gray-500 text-xs" id="newIncomeAmount"
                                    name="newIncomeAmount"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={incomeNum}
                                    onChange={(e) => setIncomeNum(e.target.value)}
                                    onClick={handleClearIncomeNum}
                                />
                            </form>
                            <i onClick={handleAddIncome} className="absolute right-0 fas fa-check text-gray-400 hover:text-green-500 text-xs p-1 m-1"></i>
                        </div>
                    )}
```

Here is my function :

```
    const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            console.log('Enter pressed')
        }
    }
```

Why is my `console.log` not responding when I press enter on my page ?

Comment: put it on the form itself or just add an event listener on mount, remember to remove it on unmount by returning the disconnect in the useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just replace `onKeyPress` with `onKeyDown` and it should work.

For enter, the keyCode will return 13. So you could

```
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('Enter pressed')
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Comment: onKeyDown takes ALL keys, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<form>`and remove this function! :)

```
const handleSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
};

...

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <fieldset>
      <input ... />
      <input ... />
   </fieldset>
   ...
</form>
```

And when you to press enter will work ;)

Comment: I got hope, but it doesn't work haha. When I click on my ```<i><i/>```, it works. When I press Enter, nothing happen 

Comment: Focused in an input?